# SQL one to many?

Tags: mysql, sql

So this is the problem I am trying to solve.

```
Category(CatID(PK), CatName,....)
Writer(wtrID(PK), CatID(FK), wtrName,....)
Report(rpID(PK), title)
Authors(rpID(FK),wtrID(FK))
```

how can I create a list to show the title of the Reports with Authors that come from exactly 3 different categories ?

Comment: Three specific categories? Or *any* three categories, as long as they are different? And do you just need the list of reports, or also any other information (such as the authors and categories, etc), and if so, in what format. Finally, there are many variants of SQL, which are *you* using? *(MySQL, SQLite, MS SQL Server, Oracle, etc?)*

Comment: Any reason why you need Authors table? FK tables are usually used for many to many relationships. You could reference Writer table from The Report table directly.

Comment: Maybe: select .... from .... join .... on .... where?

Comment: @LukeP - One `writer` can author many `reports`.  Those are the dimensions.  The `authors` table is the fact table, relating the `writer` entities to the `report` entities.

Comment: Wow super fast reply!!! :D
Using MySQL and no not specific categories, but exactly 3 not more or less, any categories, all that needs to be displayed is the title and wtrID as far as I interpreted the question, that's the exact question i posted at the end, how it was asked... :S

Comment: Q"Write a query to list the title of reports with authors that come from exactly 3 different categories."

Answer (score 3):

```
select r.title, group_concat(w.wtrID) as writer_ids
from Reports r
inner join Authors a on a.rpID = r.rpID
inner join Writer w on w.wtrID = a.wtrID
inner join Category c on c.CatID = w.CatID
group by r.title
having count(distinct c.CatID) = 3
```

Comment: OP's comment now shows a need to include the `wtrID` of the writers who authored the report.  *(But the next comment makes me think that is not actually required.)*

Comment: @user1571007 The way to thank someone on this site is to accept the answer (by clicking the check to the left of the answer) and/or upvote an answer.